# Meaning of the closure in the provided context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have the following excerpt:

> Closure to girls is a basis to be unattractive to you. They can`t be more invested and just let go. They need something to support letting go.

Here is how I understand it:

*If I will close myself to a girl she will become unattracted to me. Because she won`t be able to continue our relationships(the same as absence of investment) and she won`t be able to just left me, since there would be no reason for doing this.*

Do I understand the excerpt written above correctly? I am not asking you to help me understand the relevance of what is said in the excerpt I just would like to get the point of the excerpt meaning from the language as a tool for information convey perspective.

The part with which I struggle the most in the excerpt is the word **closure**. I really can not guess what it could refer to except being unavailable to a woman, i.e close yourself to her.

Comment: Where did that passage come from? It's not easily understood and more context could help. (As it is, several things contradict one another and there's no real way of understanding what it means. It would just be guesswork.)

Comment: @JasonBassford, there is no more context. I met the excerpt in [the](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.allsouls.dobrowins.trpquotes) app.

Comment: **a basis to be unattractive to you** is not idiomatic English.  The sentence does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure in a relationship has nothing to do with being close or closing oneself.
It's about closing it after a breakup. You get closure if both parts accept that the relationship is over, and there is little left to resolve before you can move on.

So my interpretation of the excerpt is that the girl wants closure, and a way to get that is for you to lose interest in her, and then she can let go.